# In Python, is it possible for an external function when passed a dict key, to find the other keys in that dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following code:

```
def function(k):
    # do something here

d = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' }

function(d[0])
```

Is it possible for the `function` to find out what are the other keys in the `d`? For example is there such a thing:

```
def function(k):
    print k.__parent__.keys()
```

I don't think there is such a feature (as it would be a significant security issue). However I don't know much about the technical implementation to know that for sure.

**EDIT**: The motivation was if everything in Python is an object, is it possible to find other objects that are bound to it, in this case the parent dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. Values in Python do not track where they originated from, nor are they 'bound' to one another. Containers can refer to other values, but since any value can be referenced from *multiple* locations there is no point in tracking back-references.

From `function()`s point of view, there is absolutely *no* difference between the following two invocations:

```
function(d[0])
function('a')
```

In both cases, `k` in the function is bound to a python string value, `'a'`.

If you need more context in a function, you need to pass it in explicitly:

```
def function(key, mapping):
    k = mapping[key]

function(0, d)
```

Now you have the dictionary itself too.

Comment: Thanks. The first part answers my question. I edited my question to be more clear.